# "Failed to load!" Console Developer Google

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-android-api-2, google-developers-console

When I go to my profile in https://console.developers.google.com it shows "Failed to load!" error and showing nothing in Dashboard or Activities.

Comment: What browser did you use? Have you tried it in a different browser?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Clearing the cache of browser worked for me in Chrome!

Comment: I found it easiest to just open dev tools and refresh. There's a checkbox at the top of the network panel to disable the cache while the dev tools are open. I think it's on by default.

Comment: Clearing the cache does not fix the problem. It's likely clearing cookies that fixes the problem. Regardless, as @DavidDehghan mentioned, Incognito Mode seems to work, at least as a temporary fix.

Comment: Using Google chrome browser instead of Safari helped me!

Answer (score 5):

Ad-blockers add-ons were the cause of this issue for me. Whitelisting `console.cloud.google.com` domain for ad-block solved it.

Comment: Disabled ad blocker and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If your symptoms include

1. GCP not loading project
2. Youtube and Youtube Music not playing
3. `Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin` extension is installed

Turning the extension off will fix it.

Comment: This actually was the case for me so thanks!   I had the Moesif CORS Chrome Extension enabled for some other dev work and didn't turn it off.    Someone down voted this to -1 so all I can do is bump it back up to zero.

Answer (score 2):

I got rid of this "problem" by disabling ALL extensions on Chrome. AD Blocker, Instagram downloader, etc. Everything. When you are done, close and open your browser.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had turned on the CORS policy on my web browser so make sure you are not doing the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the correct Google account, you can check that from the right-top corner in the browser, It was wrong account in my case.

Comment: Google services can also malfunction if you're logged into multiple Google accounts, even if it's showing the right one. That was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, billing was disabled, and when I enabled it, everything started working again.

Comment: It isn't answer. It is comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and some of the buttons failed to load and contents on the console page are misaligned.

In my case I have adblocker extension. All I have to do is whitelist the webpage in the adblocker extension. Now the contents of page are properly aligned and buttons are available.

Comment: try using incognito window. might fix the problem.