# Create disk in GCP console show fail to load

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-compute-engine

I created a role in GCP with below permissions

```
compute.disks.create
compute.disks.use
compute.instances.attachDisk
compute.resourcePolicies.list
compute.snapshots.list
```

however, users assigned with the role cannot 'Create Disk' in compute engine Disks page in the google console, it shows

> Failed to load.
> There was an error while loading /compute/disksAdd?project=project01&supportedpurview=project&pli=1. Please try again.
> Request ID: 10432464430460216561

[image: Create disk load error]
without showing what permissions missing. Are there any other permissions needed?

Thanks

Comment: I think you also need **compute.disks.get** and **compute.disks.list**. Edit your question and clarify what **'Create Disk' in compute engine VM** means. The permissions required are different for the GUI versus the CLI. In general, the GUI requires adding the **get** and **list** permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but even added compute.disks.get and compute.disks.list permissions, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome then try by clearing the cache. If you are not using chrome browser then try it in chrome.

If you are still facing the issues, then try using cloud shell. In the cloud console, at the bottom of the disk creation page “**Equivalent Command Line**” option will be there. Click on that link and run that command in the cloud shell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I did try clearing the cache and use chrome but still the problem persist. I was not able to click the "Equivalent Command Line" as the "Create disk" page cannot be loaded.

Comment: Can you share the page screenshot of the error?

Comment: Screenshot added in my post. Thanks

Comment: Make sure that you are using the correct Google account, you can check that from the right-top corner in the browser. Also make sure billing was not disabled, billing should be enabled for particular project. Refer [stackpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408004/failed-to-load-console-developer-google).